# Насколько безопасен account manager в Android?

Tags: android

Насколько безопасен account manager?
Как и где он хранит токены и всю другую информацию?

В доках что-то не удалось найти ничего интересно по этому поводу.

Comment: Уточните, что конкретно вас интересует?

Comment: [Похожий вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14437096/1429387) на английском.